# React TDD - How do I get inner text?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I'm doing TDD in React (with Typescript, in case that matters) to build a really simple oauth login page. Because I want to be able to support multiple providers, my first test for parameterizing my element looks like this:

```js
  it("should have providers", () => {
    const { getAllByRole } = render(<Login></Login>);
    const providers: string[] = getAllByRole("provider").map((element) => {
      return element.innerText;
    });
    expect(providers).toContain("GitHub");
  });
```

My component is very simplistic at the moment and just has the element hard-coded for now:

```js
const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div role="login">
      <header>Login with SSO</header>
      <ul>
        <li role="provider">GitHub</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

I thought my test would convert all the elements to their text content (eg: `string[]`), but instead I'm getting an array of `undefined`

```
  ● Login Component › should have providers

    expect(received).toContain(expected) // indexOf

    Expected value: "GitHub"
    Received array: [undefined]
```

I think the problem is that `innerText` isn't initialized and I am expected to call another field or method, but neither the immediate documentation for `interface HTMLElement` or intellisense in VSCode are showing me anything obvious to use instead. Perhaps my approach to testing an item is in a collection could be done altogether differently?

Comment: Can you try async and await getAllByRole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [byrole/#api](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole/#api) doc,

> Please note that setting a `role` and/or `aria-*` attribute that matches the implicit ARIA semantics is unnecessary and is not recommended as these properties are already set by the browser, and we must not use the `role` and `aria-*` attributes in a manner that conflicts with the semantics described. For example, a `button` element can't have the `role` attribute of `heading`, because the `button` element has default characteristics that conflict with the `heading` role.

You can't set the `provider` role for `li`, the default and desired role for `li` is `listitem` set by browser.

Besides, jestjs use `jsdom` as its test environment, `HTMLELement.innerText` property is not implemented in `jsdom`, see [issue#1245](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1245). You can use [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead.

`Login.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div role="login">
      <header>Login with SSO</header>
      <ul>
        <li>GitHub</li>
        <li>Google</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

`Login.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import Login from './Login';

describe('Login', () => {
  it('should have providers', () => {
    const { getAllByRole } = render(<Login />);
    const providers: Array<string | null> = getAllByRole('listitem').map((element) => {
      return element.textContent;
    });
    console.log(providers);
    expect(providers).toContain('GitHub');
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/69970652/Login.test.tsx (10.053 s)
  Login
    ✓ should have providers (124 ms)

  console.log
    [ 'GitHub', 'Google' ]

      at Object.<anonymous> (examples/69970652/Login.test.tsx:11:13)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.6 s, estimated 11 s
```

Comment: That makes sense. The blog-post I was following was manually setting the roles, so I was breaking best practice without knowing. Thank you!